# GraphQL queries for srcset

Tags: assets, craft4, graphql

I am trying to fetch srcset with GraphQL from Craft4 but I don't really understand the syntax. In my twig Templates I use `image.getSrcset(['1x','2x'],'myTransformHandle')` and I'm trying to translate that to GraphQl
If I use `srcset(sizes: ["1x","2x"])` it returns a set with the original image and one upscaled to double the size which doesn't seem that useful.
Has anyone worked with this and knows how to get a useful result?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some answers in this post right here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/11982 although it still seems like GQL srcset is highly unflexible. But maybe this helps someone:

```
myTransformHandle: image @transform(handle: "myTransformHandle") {    
    srcset(sizes:["1x","2x"])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside asset interface you can put the srcset field, here is an example:

```
{
  asset {
    srcset(sizes:["1x", "1.5x", "2x"])
  }
}
```